# Running executables in parallel and consecutively using python

Tags: python, operating-system

I have two folders. `FolderA` contains dozens of executables, `FolderB` contains an initial input file and a subsequent input file (both text files).

I would like to write a script that will do the following:

- Create folder for each of the executables
- Copy corresponding executable and a copy of the initial input file into this new folder
- Run executable for this input file
- Once process is complete, copy subsequent input file and run executable again
- End when this second process is done

This could easily be a `for` loop and I could accomplish this using the `os` package, unfortunately I'd like to see if there is a way to run this process in parallel for all the executables, or some strategic number of executables at a given iteration.

I've never done parallel processing before and I also have no idea how it can be accomplished for such a two-step execution process. Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I've also been looking into `subprocess`. Do you think this would also be a good candidate? How about `os`?

Comment: your question seems too broad, I suggest you write some code first and then submit again if you are stuck

Comment: You're right it is quite broad. I will do some research and try again. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: I recommend writing the script that does the work sequentially first. Then once it's working, go through some tutorial on multiprocessing. Write small script that runs 2 processes in paralelll e.g. `ls .`. Then combine your new knowledge with your sequential script.

Comment: you should mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for that.
Write a function which runs the entire process for a given executable:

```
def foo(exe_path):
    do stuff
```

Then feed it into map:

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(os.cpu_count() - 1)
pool.map(foo, list_of_paths)
```